# Unable to install .net 3.5 sp1 on server 2003

Tags: installation, framework

Unable to install .net 3.5 sp1 on server 2003.

Installation is aborting in the middle by displaying "sent error report to Microsoft" dialouge box

Visual Studio 2008 is installed on the system.

Comment: Can you get the details of the error and edit the question. Every bit of information helps.

Comment: After accepting the license agreement a window is appearing with a message "downloading essentials" , about 5 minutes later "sent error report to Microsoft" dialouge box is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do it the standard way, by downloading and installing.   You need to go into the System control panel and use the Add & Remove windows features  and/or Windows Update stuff (i dont remember what its really called off the top of my head) to get the .NET update.   It works a bit different on a Windows Server.   Windows Server basically has its own management tools (that the lower windows versions dont have) that allows you to add features to the system through a wizard  and update them with a different UI for the Windows Update stuff.